# Create directory and file in same command using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, new-item

I try to create a folder and a file in one PowerShell command:
I tried:

```
New-Item hello\test\ (New-Item hello\test\file.txt -type file) -type directory -Force
```

and

```
New-Item file.txt (New-Item hello\test\ -type direcotry) -type file -Force
```

But both don't seem to work as expected. 
What I want to achieve is one command to create `hello\test\file.txt`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just provide the filepath you want, including the directory, and it will work:

```
New-Item -Path '.\hello\test\file.txt' -ItemType File -Force
```

Comment: Oh god, you're right. Will accept it in some minutes.

Comment: I have to specifty the file type (PowerShell ISE v4). `New-Item -Path '.\hello\test\file.txt' -Force -ItemType File`

Comment: Yep me to, but wasn't that relevant for the question so I'll accept it. Thanks @TechSpud. Maybe edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the c.txt file in the b folder of the a folder, do so. `ni a/b/c.text -Force`

If you want to put two files y.txt and z.hml in x folder `ni x/y.txt, x/z.html -Force`

Answer (score 0):

I created the directory and the file with the following code.

```
New-Item hello\test -type Directory ; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 ; New-Item   hello\test\file.txt
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your code incorporates three cmdlets (with two relevant to the task.), not one as specified in OP's ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's not case-sensitive in powershell command, so the most convenient and fastest way to create file would be  - > **new-item -path . -name 'newfile.txt' -itemtype 'file'**

And for new directory, it's the same as in Linux-terminal ->  **mkdir newdirectory**